# Setting debuggable true for specific flavor Releases

Tags: android, gradle

How can be defined that debuggable=true is enabled in releaseBuildConfig, but just for a specific set of flavors:

This is the example code, including the trial (which does not work):

```
flavorDimensions "project", "environment"

productFlavors {
    basic  {
        dimension "project"
    }

    advanced {
        dimension "project"
    }

    flavorDevelopment {
        dimension "environment"
        applicationId "ch.myproject.app.development"
        debuggable true  // this does not work
    }

    flavorTest {
        dimension "environment"
        applicationId "ch.myproject.app.test"
        debuggable true  // this does not work

    }

    flavorIntegration {
        dimension "environment"
        applicationId "ch.myproject.app.integration"
        debuggable true  // this does not work
    }

    flavorProduction {
        dimension "environment"
        applicationId "ch.myproject.app.production"
        // just here debuggble has to be on the default (in buildTypes.debug  = on  AND in buildTypes.release = off )
        // this is working
    }
```

the "debuggable true" statements wont work in the code example above. 
But it should give you an impression, what I try to make.

The only productive Release I' gona make is the flavorProduction. 
There I'm using the default behavior which is working fine.

But all the other internal releases flavorDevelopment, flavorTest, flavor Integration, those I would like to have with enabled debugging capability.

I tried a second approach:

```
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    // setting all releases expecting the Production one to debuggable
    if (!variant.buildType.name.contains("ProductionRelease")) {
        variant.buildType.debuggable = true
    }
}
```

But there I'm getting the message:

```
Error:(132, 0) Cannot set readonly property: debuggable for class: com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.ReadOnlyBuildType
```

Does anybody know how to configure this with gradle?

thanks in advance luke

Comment: Try adding `initWith debug` at the top of the block instead of `debuggable true`.

Comment: But for this usecase it is a best practice to use `buildTypes`. `productFlavors` are used to release different flavors of the app -- like free and paid app.

Comment: Hy Bob
Correct, I'm using `buildTypes` too. I have a debug and a release buildTypes.

I could set in the `buildTypes.release` the statement  `debuggable true`, but then all Releases would be debuggable! I want to keep the flavorProduction in the default state (there release buildType has to be debuggable false). I just want the releases of the other flavors in enabled debug mode.

Comment: @Bob 
I'm not sure If I understand you correctly. Could you please make an example where to call the initWith method? Thanks Luke

Comment: I'm sorry I just mixed up different concepts. `initWith debug` works for build types because there is a build variant called debug. I think you should define new build types for these, besides debug and release.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a way to achieve this, just set **debuggable** attribute to be true in manifest in every source set of expected product flavors.

**Step 1:** Create source set of product flavors.
New source set in app/src/[flavor-name] and create a *AndroidManifest.xml* in it. Just like the following:

[image]

**Step 2:** Define **debuggable** in manifests

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <application
        android:debuggable="false"
        tools:ignore="HardCodedDebugMode" />
</manifest>
```

`tools:ignore="HardcodedDebugMode"` is used to suppress warnings.

That's it, you're good to go. No need to touch your *build.gradle* files.

Comment: this perfectly fits my need, without generating more applicationVariants.
Thanks

Comment: @Luke You're welcome. This is what I've done with my company's project.

Answer (score 20):

`debuggable` is a property of [the `BuildType` object](https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BuildType.html), and not of [the `ProductFlavor` object](https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.ProductFlavor.html), and so (as you have found), writing `debuggable true` inside a product flavor will have no effect.

Generally you will have a `debug` build type and a `release` build type, and then you will have build variants like `flavorProductionDebug` and `flavorProductionRelease`. It sounds like that's not enough for you, and you need to have whatever is different between your `debug` and `release` build types be maintained while also having `debuggable true`.

To achieve this, you can make a third build type.

```
buildTypes {
    debug { ... }
    release { ... }
    releaseDebuggable {
        initWith release
        debuggable true
    }
}
```

Now your `releaseDebuggable` build type will be exactly like your `release` build type, but debuggable!

This has the side-effect of creating a `fooReleaseDebuggable` build variant for all of your product flavors. If you want to suppress all those except for `flavorProductionReleaseDebuggable`, you could use [the `variantFilter` interface](https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.api.variant.VariantFilter.html).

Comment: Many thanks for your proposal! 
As you've mentioned there will be many applicationVariants. 
I'm using flavorDimensions, so  2 projectflavors x 4 environmentFlavors x 3 buildTypes would be result in 24 applicationVariants. Even by using variantfilters it will be a huge effort to customize the whole ci (jenkins scripts etc). 
I really cant believe there is effectively no way to modify the `buildTypes.release` configuration just for some applicationVariants...!?

Answer (score 0):

There's always a way.

```
def getCurrentFlavor() {
    String  tskReqStr = getGradle().getStartParameter()
            .getTaskRequests().toString()
     
Pattern pattern
    if( tskReqStr.contains("assemble"))
        pattern = Pattern.compile("assemble(\\w+)(Release|Debug)")
    else if(tskReqStr.contains("bundle"))
        pattern = Pattern.compile("assemble(\\w+)(Release|Debug)")
    else pattern = Pattern.compile("generate(\\w+)(Release|Debug)")
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher( tskReqStr )
    if(matcher.find())
        return matcher.group(1).toLowerCase()
    else return ""
}

android {
    buildTypes {        
        release {
            debuggable = getCurrentFlavor()
                .containsIgnoreCase(("production")
        }
        
        debug { 
            debuggable = getCurrentFlavor()
                .containsIgnoreCase(("production")
        }
    }

    flavorDimensions "enviroment"
    productFlavors {
        flavorTest { ... }
        flavorDevelopment { ... }
        flavorIntegration { ... }
        flavorProduction { ... }
    }
}
```